# Exchange Meeting Room free/busy in Sharepoint

Tags: calendar

Is there any way I can pull a resource calendar for a meeting room into Sharepoint and show if a room is booked/free and for how long respectively?

Ideally I'd like to pull in several meeting rooms and display their free/busy info in a tile-esque arrangement.

See the quick and dirty mockup I made of my ideal goal:
[image: Meeting room availability Sharepoint]

Suggestions as to how I'd approach this would really be appreciated, but simple explanation if possible please - I'm not much of a developer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a script editor in your page's list. Insert a code like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Booked')"); 
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "red");
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Free')");
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "green");
    });
</script>
```

More info. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/sharepoint-2013-list-column-status-wise-change-row-color-usi/.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Please include the essential parts of that link in your post. If the link breaks your answer will be of no help to future readers.