# Meeting room booking Application in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar

I need an interface on a SharePoint Online Page(not in the calendar) where a User can :

1. View all meeting rooms with their status and schedule(Something like [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101456/exchange-meeting-room-free-busy-in-sharepoint))
2. Can book a slot in a meeting room

Please suggest how can I achieve the same, and what technology will be best suited.

Comment: Does it need to make the actual booking of the room in the  exchange calender?

Comment: Of course yes @MortenK

Comment: Ok in that case I wont be much of help i guess. You would able to pull the data from Exchange Online (And write back) using the Microsoft Graph API. If I was to do it, I'd do it using Javascript and then embed it to a SharePoint page. Perhaps log all booking requests to a SharePoint list for error handling. I don't think the Graph API supports impersonation as of now, so the users need appropriate rights to the meeting rooms in the first place. Please do share how you are going about this :)

Comment: I got your point @MortenK, but I never used the MS Graph API nor I know how to implement it. Can you suggest me some tutorial or getting started with graph API to call the meeting resources.

Comment: Sorry I havn't been using it really - hence the "not much help" :) You can play with it here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer